How can I verify or measure faulty (suspected cracked) capacitors?
I have some devices which operate at very low average currents of about 6 µA at 3 V DC. This is to ensure multiple years of battery life. However every now and then I encounter units which have prematurely depleted the battery and investigation reveals that a ceramic capacitor (MLCC) is at fault. Careful measurement of current flow on the board and then removing decoupling capacitors one at a time has yielded good results to identify a single cap drawing tens or hundreds of µA. Often, they have been 47 µF 1210 caps.
However, after removal, I've had a difficult time definitively characterizing the failure. For example, measuring the capacitor with an LCR meter (Keysight U1733C) will give DCR measurements that start at around 1 kΩ but steadily climb to 50 MΩ or more. I would have expected a DCR around 30 kΩ, for example, for a device which had been at 106 µA prior to cap removal. ESR measurement at 1 kHz for faulty and known good caps were the same, about 450 mΩ. Capacitance measurement also generally appears to be the correct value (within tolerance), which is a bit unexpected.
I suspect the capacitor fault is a mechanical or thermal crack of some kind and am pursuing cross-sectional analysis to verify. I'm also suspecting that cracked ceramic capacitors will vary greatly and can seem intermittent because of the nature of the fault.
I have even connected the faulty capacitors to a source measure unit and applied 3 volts to see if it would draw some similar amount of current. Thus far they have not been close to the expected value (e.g. 10-20 nA instead of 100 µA).
With this in mind:

Is it the case that cracked ceramic capacitors will fluctuate or vary enough in behavior to render measurements to verify failure essentially unreliable?
Is there a measurement method that I am overlooking to better verify that these caps are indeed faulty?


Could there by any chance be flux residue between the capacitor and PCB? Flux can cause current leakage over time as metal ions accumulate in it. If you still have a PCB with a leaky cap, soak it in isopropyl alcohol for a few hours to a day (to allow it to get between the cap and board), let it dry, and then measure again.

@JonathanS. Certainly a possibility. It may be that removing the cap deemed faulty is actually incidentally cleaning flux away, and the cap is actually good. We have fairly rigorous cleaning standards, but I will bear that in mind.

47 microfarads is big for a ceramic. Are you sure it's not tantalum?

@Fred Not for low voltage in 1210 type II dielectric, they're pretty common.  E.g. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/GRJ32ER70J476KE11L/5321049

@Fred We use several manufacturers' caps, but one example of this particular cap is Samsung CL32A476KOJNNNE.

I have seen issues with no-clean flux, but not such huge leakage. I wonder if you could isolate the capacitor on the board without removing it, for example by (destructively) drilling through a via.

@SpehroPefhany I like the idea but most of these sit on a VCC track that is shared with additional capacitors such that the trace/via if cut/drilled would isolate more than one at a time. I will definitely keep this in mind as an option, but I don't know what the purpose of doing this would be. Are you proposing that cutting/drilling could be used to prepare a PCB for cross-sectional analysis without subjecting a faulty capacitor to additional thermal stress?

@JYelton If it's an intermittent problem then checking it without disturbing it might be better. Of course you could (and likely would) then remove it and check it again free of the board. tbh it sounds like you have the classic symptoms of MLCC cracking. There are some good guides on causes and there are the soft termination style of capacitors available.
